# Error: When run the react-native run-android Command

Tags: react-native

When trying react-native run-android occurs Following Error

`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > The SDK directory 'C:\Users\PC_Name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tool\platform-tools' does not exist.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > The SDK directory 'C:\Users\PC_NAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tool\platform-tools' does not exist.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:611:11)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:629:13)
at runOnAllDevices (G:\React-native\SampleApp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:74:39)
at buildAndRun (G:\React-native\SampleApp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:158:41)
at then.result (G:\React-native\SampleApp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:125:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

SYSTEM INFO

`System:
    OS: Windows 10
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-7100 CPU @ 3.90GHz
    Memory: 974.69 MB / 7.89 GB
  Binaries:
    Node: 10.13.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
    npm: 6.4.1 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: Version  3.4.0.0 AI-183.6156.11.34.5522156
  npmPackages:
    react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0
    react-native: 0.61.1 => 0.61.1`

I'm trying to change the gradlew file permission but its not working.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Looks like sdk is not found.Try to follow the setup guide and set the paths.

Comment: U need to install PLATFORM TOOLS